# Docker and nginx upstream zero downtime

Tags: nginx, docker

I'm Having some wierd issues trying to automate the deployment of docker containers using nginx's upstream directive.  For some reason when I manually do the following it works but when I try to automate it I do not get consistent results.

Basically I pull the latest image
stop, remove the 1 of 2 running containers
Then start the container
Then update nginx upstream conf file
Reload nginx config.
Repeat for 2nd container.

Seems simple but for some reason I can' get this to work in a bash script all the time. I'm using seige to load test the application.

`siege -d1 -t75S -c25 http://192.168.49.4:8087`

My Script to automate the deployment
The latest images is pulled prior to running the script.

```
#! /bin/bash

appname=appnamexyz;
appport=8000;
host_ip=192.168.49.4;
registry=192.168.254.96;

echo "upstream api_servers {${nl}
  server $(docker port ${appname}-1 ${appport}) max_fails=2 fail_timeout=1s;${nl}
  server $(docker port ${appname}-2 ${appport}) max_fails=2 fail_timeout=1s;${nl}
}" > /etc/nginx/conf.d/api_upstream.conf

sed -i "s/server $(docker port $appname-1 $appport)/server xxx/g" /etc/nginx/conf.d/api_upstream.conf

docker stop $appname-1
docker rm -f $appname-1
docker run -d --name $appname-1 -p $host_ip::$appport $registry:5000/$appname -APIKey=e5e1c4b8e46d563c3 

sed -i "s/server xxx/server $(docker port $appname-1 $appport)/g" /etc/nginx/conf.d/api_upstream.conf
nginx -s reload



sleep 15s

sed -i "s/server $(docker port $appname-2 $appport)/server xxx/g" /etc/nginx/conf.d/api_upstream.conf

docker stop $appname-2
docker rm -f $appname-2
docker run -d --name $appname-2 -p $host_ip::$appport $registry:5000/$appname -APIKey=e5e1c4b8e46d563c350b7

sed -i "s/server xxx/server $(docker port $appname-2 $appport)/g" /etc/nginx/conf.d/api_upstream.conf
nginx -s reload
cat /etc/nginx/conf.d/api_upstream.conf
```

The application will return 200s then while restarting the second container I'll receive 500,502 errors.
Here is my conf file for the app.

```
server {
  listen 8087;
  server_name 192.168.49.4;

  location / {
    proxy_pass http://api_servers;
    proxy_next_upstream     error timeout invalid_header http_500 http_502 http_504;
    proxy_connect_timeout   1;
  }
}
```

What should I do to remediate this?

Comment: I see a typo in the command line for starting the 2nd container: `$ap  pname` should become `$appname`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While 502 corresponds to backend timout, 500 is a server error, indicating a misconfiguration. You might wish to fix the following on first hand:

Before the sleep, you actually replaced the first line of `api_upstream.conf` with

```
sed -i "s/server xxx/server $(docker port $appname-1 $appport)/g" /etc/nginx/conf.d/api_upstream.conf
```

(You even do it twice... purpose? Double copy-paste?)

But what you have not done yet at that time is replacing the second line, which remains being

```
server $(docker port ${appname}-2 ${appport}) max_fails=2 fail_timeout=1s;${nl}
```

I suppose `$appname` and `$appport` are empty, making the subshell fail/being empty, meaning that this line is actually interpreted as

```
server max_fails=2 fail_timeout=1s;
```

When load-balancing the requests with the default round-robin, nginx might face a problem there...

You should ensure that the `api_upstream.conf` always contains valid data as soon as it is used. You may add `server`s in there later, but letting a partially written placeholder will won't produce any good.

Comment: Your statement about 5xx errors is not true. It only means this is a **server side** error. Nginx will return `504` if it timed out connecting / reading from upstream servers or `502` if all upstream servers are down.

Comment: Right, answer corrected

Comment: I do it twice to be able to identify the server in the upstream that I want to replace with the new ip:port. The second one isn't replaced until the new container is up and running.

Comment: So while you only have the first container running, you have one `server` in `upstream` which is incorrect. nginx would not even load that incorrect configuration since it does does pass `nginx -t`. I am surprised it works at all.

Comment: Are you saying that having one server listed in the upstream would not pass nginx -t or that the upstream has one live server accepting requests so it will always fail? I tried leaving one server listed in the upstream and nginx -t passed. I'm using nginx 1.6.2 on centos 6.5.  However I think I understand you what you mean now.

Comment: Oh no sorry I just got what you were doing with your upstreams. You are just using a placeholder while creating the docker container, for whatever reason. Are the 500 errors coming from nginx? Check its error log, you will have an explanation there. If not then it is backend trouble unrelated with nginx. Try to dig its files too if needed.

Answer (score 1):

I've had something of the same issue myself: the container startup times just aren't the same accross deployments of the image... Thus restarting a container from a container isn't always as fast... It might just be that you'd have to setup some kind of consistency check before rotating the other container ... You might even want to hit the container from the shell script to do a healthcheck instead of just waiting an arbitrary 15sec... ?